# Sum of square representations

Tags: number-theory

How can I find the number of proper representations of a number n as a sum of 2 squares where $n \le 10000$ ?

How to calculate such a thing?

Comment: why $n \leq 10000?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks more like a programming question and the upper bound on $n$ is very small, you can simply iterate over the $\sqrt{\frac{10000}{2}}\approx 70$ possible values of one of the squares and just check if the difference between $n$ and this square is a square too.

Even faster approach is to have two variables, one corresponding to the "(S)maller" (starting at $1$) and one to the "(L)arger" square (starting from the greatest possible value used in the representation) and keep moving them towards each other until they meet. In pseudo-code:

- Let $S=1$ and $L=\sqrt{10000}$.
- While $S\leq L$, calculate $S^2 + L^2$:

  - If the result is smaller than $n$, increase $S$.
  - If the result is greater than $n$, decrease $L$.
  - Otherwise it must be equal to $n$, so record one "successful hit" and increase $S$ and decrease $L$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $n$ cannot have any prime factors $3$ modulo $4$. This is Fermat's Two Square theorem which you might want to check out.

Also, there is a function associated with this. See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

Comment: If $n$ has a prime factor $p$ equivalent to $3$ mod $4$ it must occur to an even power in the prime factorisation of $n$. e.g. $12^2+6^2=180=2^2\times 3^2\times 5$ is divisible by $3$. If $n=p^{2a}r$ then the representations of $n$ correspond to the representations of $r$.